# assigning values of string array to properties of an object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a stirng array :  `values: string['myName', 'myLastname', 'myAge']`
and want to assign each value to each property of an object: `myModel={name:'', lastname:'', age:''}` peer to peer.
I try to code this as:

```
let i =0;
Object.keys(this.myModel).forEach((key) => {
    this.myModel[key] = this.values[i];
    i++;
  });
```

but I get error..., How can do it?

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w8Kl4W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare and use i for index, forEach on object keys can do it with the second parameter:

```
Object.keys(this.myModel).forEach((key,i) => {
    this.myModel[key] = this.values[i];
});
```

Also, don't do: `values: string['myName', 'myLastname', 'myAge'];`
go with `values: string[] = ['myName', 'myLastname', 'myAge'];`

Other than that, your code does seem to work - although it might depend on the IDE you're using if it's going to throw the error. So try with these changes.